# How to set data for my extension attribute Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, rest-api, custom-attributes, extension-attributes, savedata

I can't set the value for my extension attribute , how to set the value for extension attribute using json array swagger. And i can't show the data in the order grid.

The below attribute and value can't set.

```
My attribute : customer_feedback

Value : Hello
```

My Module that created for extension attribute

**Sm\OrderFeedback\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- File: app/code/Sm/OrderFeedback/etc/di.xml -->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="sm_orderfeedback_add_order_extension_attribute"
                type="Sm\OrderFeedback\Plugin\OrderRepositoryPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Sm\OrderFeedback\etc\extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- File: app/code/Sm/OrderFeedback/etc/extension_attributes.xml -->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="customer_feedback" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

**Sm\OrderFeedback\Setup\InstallSchema.php**

```
namespace Sm\OrderFeedback\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
 * Class InstallSchema
 */
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * Custom order column
     */
    const ORDER_FEEDBACK_FIELD = 'customer_feedback';

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $setup->getTable('sales_order'),
            self::ORDER_FEEDBACK_FIELD,
            [
                'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'size' => 255,
                'nullable' => true,
                'comment' => 'Customer Feedback'
            ]
        );
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**Sm\OrderFeedback\Plugin\OrderRepositoryPlugin.php**

```
<?php
/* File: app/code/Sm/OrderFeedback/Plugin/OrderRepositoryPlugin.php */

namespace Sm\OrderFeedback\Plugin;

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderSearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

/**
 * Class OrderRepositoryPlugin
 */
class OrderRepositoryPlugin
{
    /**
     * Order feedback field name
     */
    const FIELD_NAME = 'customer_feedback';

    /**
     * Order Extension Attributes Factory
     *
     * @var OrderExtensionFactory
     */
    protected $extensionFactory;

    /**
     * OrderRepositoryPlugin constructor
     *
     * @param OrderExtensionFactory $extensionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(OrderExtensionFactory $extensionFactory)
    {
        $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Add "customer_feedback" extension attribute to order data object to make it accessible in API data
     *
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param OrderInterface $order
     *
     * @return OrderInterface
     */
    public function afterGet(OrderRepositoryInterface $subject, OrderInterface $order)
    {
        $customerFeedback = $order->getData(self::FIELD_NAME);
        $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();
        $extensionAttributes->setCustomerFeedback($customerFeedback);
        $order->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

        return $order;
    }

    /**
     * Add "customer_feedback" extension attribute to order data object to make it accessible in API data
     *
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param OrderSearchResultInterface $searchResult
     *
     * @return OrderSearchResultInterface
     */
    public function afterGetList(OrderRepositoryInterface $subject, OrderSearchResultInterface $searchResult)
    {
        $orders = $searchResult->getItems();

        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            $customerFeedback = $order->getData(self::FIELD_NAME);
            $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
            $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();
            $extensionAttributes->setCustomerFeedback($customerFeedback);
            $order->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        }

        return $searchResult;
    }
}
```

My Request API

```
 {
  "entity": {
        "base_currency_code": "USD",
        "base_discount_amount": -4.5,
        "base_grand_total": 45.5,
        "base_shipping_amount": 5,
        "base_subtotal": 45,
        "base_tax_amount": 0,
        "customer_email": "Rbjah@test.com",
        "customer_firstname": "vins",
        "customer_group_id": 1,
        "customer_id": 200,
        "customer_is_guest": 0,
        "customer_lastname": "RBJ",
        "customer_note_notify": 1,
        "discount_amount": -4.5,
        "email_sent": 1,
        "coupon_code": "Test1",
        "discount_description": "Test1",
        "grand_total": 45.5,
        "is_virtual": 0,
        "order_currency_code": "USD",
        "shipping_amount": 5,
        "shipping_description": "Flat Rate - Fixed",
        "state": "new",
        "status": "pending",
        "store_currency_code": "USD",
        "store_id": 1,
        "store_name": "Main Website\nMain Website Store\n",
        "subtotal": 45,
        "subtotal_incl_tax": 45,
        "tax_amount": 0,
        "total_item_count": 19,
        "total_qty_ordered": 19,
        "weight": 1,
        "items": [
        {
            "base_discount_amount": 4.5,
            "base_original_price": 45,
            "base_price": 45,
            "base_price_incl_tax": 45,
            "base_row_invoiced": 0,
            "base_row_total": 45,
            "base_tax_amount": 0,
            "base_tax_invoiced": 0,
            "discount_amount": 4.5,
            "discount_percent": 10,
            "free_shipping": 0,
            "is_virtual": 0,
            "name": "Push It Messenger Bag",
            "original_price": 45,
            "price": 20,
            "price_incl_tax": 45,
            "product_id": 14,
            "product_type": "simple",
            "qty_ordered": 12,
            "row_total": 240,
            "row_total_incl_tax": 240,
            "sku": "24-WB04",
            "store_id": 1
        },{
            "base_discount_amount": 4.5,
            "base_original_price": 45,
            "base_price": 27.00,
            "base_price_incl_tax": 45,
            "base_row_invoiced": 0,
            "base_row_total": 45,
            "base_tax_amount": 0,
            "base_tax_invoiced": 0,
            "discount_amount": 4.5,
            "discount_percent": 10,
            "free_shipping": 0,
            "is_virtual": 0,
            "name": "Sprite Stasis Ball 65 cm",
            "original_price": 45,
            "price": 10,
            "price_incl_tax": 45,
            "product_id": 14,
            "product_type": "simple",
            "qty_ordered": 1,
            "row_total": 10,
            "row_total_incl_tax": 10,
            "sku": "24-WG082-pink",
            "store_id": 1
        }
        ],
        "billing_address": {
            "address_type": "billing",
            "city": "Ahmedabad",
            "company": "Rbj",
            "country_id": "US",
            "email": "Rbjah@test.com",
            "firstname": "Rbjah",
            "lastname": "sasasa",
            "postcode": "30332",
            "region": "Georgia",
            "region_code": "GA",
            "region_id": 19,
            "street": [
                "Street 1",
                "Street 2"
            ],
            "telephone": "123456"
        },
        "payment": {
            "method": "cashondelivery"
        },
        "extension_attributes": {
            "shipping_assignments": [
                {
                    "shipping": {
                        "address": {
                            "address_type": "shipping",
                            "city": "Ahmedabad",
                            "company": "Rbjah",
                            "country_id": "US",
                            "customer_address_id": 2,
                            "email": "Rbjah@test.com",
                            "firstname": "Rbjah",
                            "lastname": "sasasa",
                            "postcode": "30332",
                            "region": "Georgia",
                            "region_code": "GA",
                            "region_id": 19,
                            "street": [
                                "Street 1",
                                "Street 2"
                            ],
                            "telephone": "123456"
                        },
                        "method": "flatrate_flatrate"
                    }
                }
            ],
      "customer_feedback": "Hello"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you checked sales_order table has your new column has store any feedback ?

Comment: No it is null only

Comment: so where customer enter feeed back ?

Comment: I will set using the sales order repository API

Comment: How customer enter feedback ?

Comment: please check and update me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Msquare. We are trying to add value for the extension attribute during order creation using Rest API. Our Magento version 2.3.4. The order was created successfully, but the value is not set for extension attribute. Please find above "My Request API" to view request JSON

Comment: There is no save method in the OrderRepositoryPlugin.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once you save your attribute **customer_feedback** value in table **sales_order**. Then add this two files in your module.

**app/code/VendoreName/MoudleName/view/adminhtml/layout**

**sales_order_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="sales_order_grid"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/MoudleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component**

**sales_order_grid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="customer_feedback">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Customer Feedback</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

> **Run Magento Command**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

> if not see your column then click on **Columns** like below screenshot, tick you column check box.

[image]

***I Hope This Helps You.***