# Where is the extensions attribute magento 2 actually save in Database?

Tags: magento2, extension-attributes

For example, I've added an extension attribute to order

```
<!-- etc/extension_attributes.xml -->   
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">   
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">  
    <attribute code="tigren_attribute" type="Tigren\Example\Api\Data\TigrenAttributeInterface" />
    </extension_attributes> 
</config>
```

after an order is saved , where can i find the ext attr in Db?

Comment: See https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/310414/4564

Answer (score 5):

Currently, extension attributes are only about Web API. **You need to save extension attributes manually using plugins on appropriate services.**

**If you want to save Extension Attributes to DB than you need to add column.**

Regarding DB : It stores to the relative table of entity.

For Example:

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\RuleInterface">
    <attribute code="start_date" type="string" />
    <attribute code="end_date" type="string" />
    <attribute code="brands" type="string" />
</extension_attributes>
```

Above code is for Sales Rule Extension Attributes, So it will store to `RuleInterface` related table that is salesrule.

Answer (score -1):

I created a new Table, now I want to get a column of this table i can do that?
I tried with the following code but it's not working as per the expectation.

```
 $customerData->setCustomAttribute('computer_brand', $computerBrand)
                ->setCustomAttribute('computer_model', $computerModel)
                ->setCustomAttribute('entity_id', $customerId);
```